# Why the usage of tokens in an identifier gets errored?

Tags: c, identifier

Using '-' in an identifier cause the error:

```
‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘-’ token
```

Why this happenned?

Comment: Is `a-b` subtraction of two variables or a single variable?

Comment: Distict variables. So, it will consider as seperate identifier.

Comment: If that's the hyphen (rather than en-dash or em-dash), it *is* a token. It's used for subtraction.

Comment: Re "*If that's the hyphen*", It is, though I suppose it could have been mangled along the way. And that would be the reason to disallow EN DASH and EM DASH: Too confusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`-` belongs to a class of tokens known as *punctuators*, which include `.`, `!`, `*`, `+`, etc.  Punctuators may not be part of identifiers.

The only characters that may be used in identifiers are:

- an underscore `_`;
- Upper- and lowercase Latin alphabet characters (`A-Z`, `a-z`);
- decimal digits (`0-9`);
- universal character names (`\Uxxxx` or `\uxxxx`, where `x` represents a hexadecimal digit);
- other implementation-defined characters (i.e. unicode or extended characters).

Furthermore, identifiers must not start with a digit character - the compiler will reject identifiers like `2good` or `7Up`. And although compilers typically don’t enforce it, you should not use leading underscores in your identifiers - such names are reserved to the implementation, meaning code in the standard library headers and elsewhere.  If you name one of your variables or functions with a leading underscore, that may conflict with a variable or function name declared in a standard header.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot use the hyphen in an identifier since it *is* a token in the C language, despite your contention. It's the subtraction operator, or unary minus.

What would you expect to happen with the following code, were identifiers allowed to contain the `-` character?

```
int some = 42;
int value = 12;
int some-value = 99;
printf("%d\n", some-value);
```

Should that print the `some-value` variable `99`? Or the `some - value` expression, which evaluates to `30`?

If you want that sort of formatting (lower case words with an obvious separator), you're better off just using the underscore character `_`. This is commonly called snake case:

```
int some_value = 99;
```

Comment: No. It will error with lvalue required. My question is wrong. I suspected in the sense of identifier but not as a token.

Comment: @sat.learner: yes, I know what it will do *now,* I was more asking what you thought it *should* do, were identifiers allowed to contain the hyphen character. I'll make that clearer.

Comment: How can we do so.

Comment: @sat.learner: how can we do *what,* exactly? There's no way to use `-` in an identifier, it's not one of the legal characters. If you mean something that *looks* like that, I've added the snake case paragraph to my answer, since `_` *is* legal.

Comment: I think i have a negative reputation for asking unnecessary questions. I have formatted it correctly. Can you pls recheck again. Because, SO doesn't allow me ask new questions. I can able to ask questions as suggested. Next time, Will ask needed questions accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

> '-' is not used as token in c standard.

Your premise is wrong. - is used as a token. Quote from C11 standard draft:

> 6.4 Lexical elements
>
> Syntax
>
> ```
> token:
>     ...
>     punctuator
> ```

> 6.4.6 Punctuators
>
> Syntax
>
> ```
> punctuator:
> ... - ...
> ```

Ellipses represent an omission.

---

> When will '-' character be represented in an identifier?

Never, I suspect. It would be ambiguous with the minus operators.